# Open PlayStore from link without opening browser in android

Tags: android, google-play, android-webview

I am trying to open this [LINK](http://fkrt.it/gPgFQuuuuN)  on button click which first opens in browser then launches the play store.

I want that on button click it should directly open the playstore instead of opening the browser. What should i do?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Comment: For that you need to provide the plain link. Play store doesn't know anything about your shortened url.